# Folder name changed when SCP from iPhone to Synology server

Tags: scp, iphone, synology

This is the first time I've posted here.

I've used the    scp    command from iPhone ios 8.4 (jailbroken) Mterminal to transfer a folder over to my Synology NAS.

```
scp -P "private port" -r "location_in_iPhone/$NOW" username@hostname:"directory_in_Synology_NAS"
```

The name of the folder in iPhone is a variable that I've put in a shell script with auto creation of date and time    "NOW=$(date +F%-%R)"

Problem is, the name of the folder becomes some random words like    "2VI05A~0"    when I view the folder of my NAS from Windows or Ubuntu.

But when I view the folder from iPhone or Synology itself, it's what I wanted from    ""NOW=$(date +F%-%R)"

How can I    scp    and have the same folder name read from any OS?

Comment: No one able to help?